# Persist Keyboard on Button Press

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have made chat application and whenever I press send button on the right of textInput, the keyboard closes. I want to persist the keyboard on send button (check button) press.[image]

This is the code sample please check.

```
class MessageForm extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.handleMessageChange = message => {
      this.props.updateMessage(message);
    };

    this.handleButtonPress = () => {
      this.props.sendMessage(this.props.message, this.props.receiver.uid);
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (!prevProps.sendingError && this.props.sendingError) {
      Alert.alert('Error', this.props.sendingError);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const sending = this.props.sending;
    const isButtonDisabled = sending || this.props.message.trim().length === 0;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInput}
          placeholder={'Write something ...'}
          placeholderTextColor={Colors.textColorLight}
          returnKeyType="send"
          onChangeText={this.handleMessageChange}
          value={this.props.message}
          underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
          editable={!sending}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={this.handleButtonPress}
          onBlur={() => this.input.focus()}
          disabled={isButtonDisabled}>
          <CustomIcon
            vectorIcon
            name="checkcircle"
            type="antdesign"
            size={40}
            color={Colors.messageSendButtonColor}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Find out how to show the keyboard, then do that right after sending.

Comment: Did that, but it closes and then open the keyboard. Doesn't look good, obviously.

Comment: You need to share code in that case. Is the message input field rendered throughout? How are you processing a tap on the send button? Etc. If sending just clears the input, the keyboard shouldn't disappear I'd think, so it must be something you're doing.

Comment: I am not sure if the tap processing matters, I am just calling an api to save the data to server.

Comment: Not providing code is one of the "close question" reasons, so not sure what else I can tell you at this point. Even if the tap processing doesn't matter, you're still having this problem but haven't provided any code for us to look at. How exactly are we supposed to help? Randomly guess?

Comment: Have uploaded the code @ChrisG

Answer (score 0):

You can use `blurOnSubmit={false}` prop for `<TextInput>`.

Comment: Well this will only work with keyboard submit button (return key). But doesn't work with custom button here like this.

Comment: Then wrap it in a `<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'>`. You can also use the `keyboardDismissMode` to handle the scrolling!

Comment: Doesn't work. Since the problem is button tap, which runs independent to what it's encapsulated in.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue. The keyboard is closing because I am disabling `TextInput` using `editable` flag  while message is being sent, that makes the keyboard get closed. So I removed it and it works like a charm.